# Not able to get successful login in web page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

here is the code
I am not able to get the message as successful login despite debugging in console whereas directly entering the php link with username & password in browser directly is working perfectly

The output I'm getting is " INcorrect Login information. Please Try Again".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<script src="/_js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login').submit(function() {
var formData = $(this).serialize();
$.post('login.php',formData,processData).error('ouch');
function processData(data) {
      console.log(data==='pass');
    if (data==='pass') {
       $('.main').html('<p>You have successfully logged in!</p>');
    } else {
       if ($('#fail').length === 0) {
         $('#formwrapper').prepend('<p id="fail">Incorrect login information. Please try again</p>');
      }
    }
  } // end processData
return false;
  }); // end submit

}); // end ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <p class="logo">Demo LOGIn</p>
</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div id="formwrapper">
        <form method="POST" action="../_php/login.php" id="login">
<p>
    <label for="Username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="Password">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
 </p>
 </form>
 </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and here is php file

```
 $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Password']);
 $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password from Use_Pass WHERE     Username='$Username'");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
echo 'pass';
}
else {
echo 'fail';
}


mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
 $('#login').submit(function()
  {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('login.php', $("#login").serialize(), function(response)
      {

        if ($.trim(response) == 'pass') {
          $('.main').html('<p>You have successfully logged in!</p>');
        } else {
          if ($('#fail').length === 0) {
            $('#formwrapper').prepend('<p id="fail">Incorrect login information. Please try again</p>');
          }
        }

      }
    );
  }
 ); // end submit

  }
); // end ready
</script>
```

Please use this updated code, make sure the url is passed correctly. I hope this will help.

Comment: No. Nothing happened.
same result.

And I was using get to see the link going to server by debugging console which can't be seen in POST method though POST is recommendable for security purposes.

Comment: ok then you should better update the jquery post function you are using. It can be done easily without complex post function you are using for jquery. If you say i will edit my answer and give you an example code for your login system you want to check

Comment: please check the updated answer only javascript part is updated

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file, it looks like you're trying to get a username of exactly `$Username`. You will need to concatenate it to be getting the variable instead of that string itself.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password from Use_Pass WHERE Username='".$Username."');
```

Comment: the solution didn't work.
And I think there's a double quotation missing in query.